# how to add(or ignore) XML namespace when using XElement.Load

Tags: c#, linq, namespaces, xelement

I am creating XML using Linq to XML and C#. It all works great except when I need to manually add in a row in the XML. This row is only added if I have a value to pass through to it, otherwise I just ignore the entire tag.

I use XElement.Load to load in the string of text that I store in a string but when I attach it to the XML it always puts in xmlns="" at the end of my tag.

Is there a way I can tell XElement.Load to use the existing namespace or to ignore it when putting in the string to the XML?

Ideally I just want my string to be included to the XML being created without extra tags being added.

Below is a sample of what I currently do:

```
string XMLDetails = null;
if (ValuePassedThrough != null)
XMLDetails = "<MyNewTag Code=\"14\" Value=\"" + ValuePassedThrough +"\"></MyNewTag>";
```

When I build up the XML I load the above string into my XML. It is here where xmlns="" is being added to the XMLDetails value but ideally I want this ignored as it is causing issues with the recipient when they try to read this tag.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://namespace-address";
    XNamespace xsi = "http://XMLSchema-instance-address";

XDocument RequestDoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(ns + "HeaderTag",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ns),
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://www.addressofschema.xsd"),
        new XAttribute("Version", "1"),
            new XElement(ns + "OpeningTAG",
```

...My XML Code ...

```
XElement.Load(new StringReader(XMLDetails))
```

...End of XML Code ...

As mentioned above. My code works, it successfully outputs XML for me. Its just the MyNewTag tag I load in using XElement.Load gets xmlns="" added to the end of it which is causing me an issue.

Any ideas how I can work around this? Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Rich

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
XElement withoutNamespace = XElement.Load(new StringReader(XMLDetails));
XElement withNamespace = new XElement(ns + withoutNamespace.Name.LocalName,
                                      withoutNamespace.Nodes());
```

As a better alternative - why don't you either include the namespace when you're building up the XML, or even better, create an `XElement` instead of manually generating an XML string which you then read. Manually creating XML is very rarely a good idea. Aside from anything else, you're assuming that `ValuePassedThrough` has already been escaped, or doesn't need escaping etc. That *may* be valid - but it's at least a cause for concern.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help. Your answer makes sense but when I try to use your suggestion VS tells me that System.Xml.Linq.XElement does not contain a definition for 'LocalName'. I agree with your point on manually building up the XML as a string but if I need to apply logic how can I do this in the middle of creating the XML when building it with Linq? Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops, edited to get the local name of the XName. You can build up the XML in the same way you do now - just make XMLDetails an XElement instead of a string. Unfortunately it's not entirely clear how you're using XMLDetails later on, but this should work fine. If not, please give more details - or preferably a short but complete program.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
XElement XMLDetails = new XElement(ns + "OpeningTAG", new XElement(ns + "MyNewTag", new XAttribute("Code", 14), new XAttribute("Value", 123)));

XDocument RequestDoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(ns + "HeaderTag",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ns),
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://www.addressofschema.xsd"),
        new XAttribute("Version", "1"),
            XMLDetails));
```